# Apparent IP doesn't take me to website

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ping

I noticed that sometimes, when ping requesting a website, I receive an IP Address that doesn't in fact take me to that domain name. It instead takes me to the default server page.

For example, if I were to ping a theoretical domain (1234abcd.com):

```
$ ping 1234abcd.com
PING 1234abcd.com (123.4.567.890) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 123.4.567.890: icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=0.000001ms
64 bytes from 123.4.567.890: icmp_req=2 ttl=48 time=100000.0ms 
^C
--- 1234abcd.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 420ms
```

But then if I were to visit `123.4.567.890` I would receive:

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

then checking 1234abcd.com again I get the full website.

Comment: Probably the server uses virtualhosts

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If that is the case, how could I navigate to the original domain via the IP?

Comment: What do you mean `original domain`? Do you mean the default web site? If so, you've already seen how to get there. Navigate to the ip address. That will take you to the default web site.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

The IP address only identifies the server. The same server can host more than one website. Thee is no reason this should be surprising.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the IP address but you do not know the host name, then there is no way for you to get to the web site.

The web server is probably running virtual hosts, which work by checking the Host: HTTP header. If you don't provide that header, the server has no idea what site to give you.

Some servers are configured to give you a list of the sites at an IP, but not very many servers do that.